# Automatically unpack a tuple in a function call in C++

Tags: c++, range-v3

I am using range-v3 and sometimes I used `ranges::views::enumerate` to have the id of the value that I'm iterating on. `enumerate` view returns a tuple containing the id and the value, so I would like to know if its possible to unpack directly that tuple. This would be an example:

```
samplers | 
    ranges::views::enumerate | 
    ranges::views::transform([](const auto samplerId, const auto &jSampler){...} |
    ranges::to_vector;
```

Comment: `[](const auto& p) {const auto& [samplerId, jSampler] = p; /*...*/}`?

Comment: So there is no way to define that in the declaration directly? Just thinking that it would much better to see the declaration of the function and see that it receives two parameters.

Comment: But it doesn't receive 2 parameters. `enumerate` returns a tuple like thing which is a single object. Even if you give the 2 parts of the parameter different names, it would be a single parameter. e.g. in C++20, I think you can write `([](auto const [samplerId, jSampler) {...})` but again, it's still a single parameter

Comment: I understand that is 1 single parameter, but in the C++20 snippet, at least it shows it is unpacked to two values, so feels better. I think it is close enough to what I was thinking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpacking a range of tuples into n-ary function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484633/unpacking-a-range-of-tuples-into-n-ary-function)

Comment: Actually, that looks pretty nice!